# Google Protocol Buffer not compiling for C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

This is my first attempt to write a prototype with Google Protocol Buffer. My file looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package Clark.EDI.Protos;

// [START csharp_declaration]
option csharp_namespace = "Clark.EDI.Protos";
// [END csharp_declaration]

// [START messages]
message Address {
  required int32 addressId = 1;
  optional string namePrimary = 2;
  optional string nameSecondary = 3;
  optional string streetPrimary = 4;
  optional string streetSecondary = 5;
  optional string city = 6;
  optional string stateCode = 7;  
  optional string zipCode = 8;
  optional string countryCode = 9;  
}
// [END messages]
```

I'm trying to compile it like this:

> protoc --csharp_out=src address.proto

Even tho I define it as proto3, it's asking for required or optional.

When I include the `required` or `optional` I receive these messages, but no .cs file.

> address.proto:1:1: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 239.
>   address.proto:1:1: Expected top-level statement (e.g. "message").
>   address.proto:1:2: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 187.
>   address.proto:1:3: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 191.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: 239 is likely a unicode byte order mark, save the file as ansi

Comment: From visual studio? What Encoding?

Comment: required/optional are removed in proto3

Answer (score 2):

I think your text editor is silently inserting byte order marks at the beginning of your `address.proto` file. The error messages imply that the first three bytes in the file are `239 187 191`, or `EF BB BF`, which is the UTF-8 byte order mark:

```
Encoding    Hexadecimal    Decimal        CP1252 characters
UTF-8       EF BB BF       239 187 191    ï»¿
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding)

Which text editor are you using? If you are on Windows, try opening the file in Notepad or Notepad++. If you fiddle with the Encoding settings you should see 3 unexpected characters at the start of the file. Remove them.

Comment: I changed the options to save this to UTF-8 without signature, and now receive the message: `address.proto:1:18: Unrecognized syntax identifier "proto3".  This parser only recognizes "proto2".` I downloaded 2.6.1 from here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue because I had copied it from the pdf. After I coded it by hand, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using protoc binary v3, the required/optional keywords are removed.

So, remove all  required/optional keywords

I compiled your message using V3 and it's compiled successfully after removing required/optional keywords.

note: 
Save your file as ANSI or UTF-8, don't save as UniCode.

you can install v3 as nuget package

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turned out that I accidentally put non-breaking whitespace into .proto file (probably by some shortcut in my IDE). It can be checked by searching '\xa0' using for example notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on Visual Studio 2019 because I had copied the .proto text from an online pdf file and the text was in **UTF-8 encoding**.

error messages:

Interpreting non ascii codepoint 205.

Interpreting non ascii codepoint 190.

What I did is select all text in notepad++ and in encoding menu --> **convert to ANSI**, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue also, and it turned out to be a symptom of having the .proto file name be same as one of the names of the messages.  For example:

**myProto**.proto file included

```
syntax = "proto2";

message myProto
{
    // a bunch of stuff
}
```

Changing the file name to **myProtoFile**.proto preserved the uniquness and satisfied the need for proto message names to be different from the proto file name... obvious in hind sight, but took me a bit to get there.